# HDMI audio pin-out

Tags: audio, video, hdmi

I have two HDMI outputs, one of them has only video, the other only sound. What I want to do is combine two HDMI cables and get the video and sound at the same time with only one HDMI cable. But I am not sure which pin numbers to combine. Can you help me with this?

Comment: what is the result of your research?  ... what is your actual question? ... `Can you help me with this?` is not a question about HDMI cables

Comment: @jsotola What I want to do is to join two different hdmi cables because only one has video and the other only audio. I don't know if there is a device that does this or can I cut some pins of the video cable and combine it with the outputs of the audio cable?

Answer (score 5):

There are no pins that you can simply combine.

The audio in an HDMI interface is embedded in the same high speed data lines as the video data signalling (within the blanking periods of the video data).

As a result you would need some active electronics to take a video input and audio input and combine both into a single HDMI interface. This would be a fairly complicated device to build unless you have a background in high speed serial interfaces and devices such as FPGAs.

There are off-the-shelf solutions for combining DVI (*) and audio into a single HDMI interface. Product recommendations are off topic, however you should be able to find what you are looking for by searching for DVI Audio HDMI Combiner or some combination thereof.

---

(*) DVI uses the same high speed serial interface as HDMI - essentially it is just HDMI without the audio and sideband channel.